# Cannot access regedit

Tags: windows-7, regedit

I tried to alter the default path for "Program Files," but was unsuccessful, and made some other change inadvertently. Now, I cannot open `regedit`. The error says:

> "Windows cannot find [path to regedit]".

Is there some other program I can use to change back the altered registry keys? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

(this is under Windows 7 Ultimate)

Comment: Can you run `%SystemRoot%\system32\regedit.exe`?

Comment: @grawity: `regedit.exe` is not located in the `system32` folder. At least not on 64 bit Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: Ah, I forgot... `%SystemRoot%\regedit.exe` then?

Comment: @grawity: There is always a copy in `%SystemRoot%`. There is also one in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` on 64 bit Windows 7, so `%SystemRoot%\system32` might also contain one in the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of things you could try:

1. If you have **System Restore** enabled, boot from your installation disc, choose *Repair your computer* and pick an restore point before the changes to your registry.
2. You should be able to open `regedit` by **specifying the full path**. Press `[Windows] + R` and type in `C:\Windows\regedit.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of the modified keys you can use the command line REG utility, which is built into Windows.

From an [elevated command prompt](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt/):

```
reg import C:\mybackup.reg
```

Comment: I can't even open cmd.exe :(.
(says the same thing)

Comment: Try downloading this [reg file](http://download.bleepingcomputer.com/reg/FixNCR.reg) to your desktop, then double click it. It may fix it.

Comment: It says the same thing when trying to run that file to

Comment: @Amazed: Importing `.reg` files requires `regedit`...

Comment: @grawity I believe the shell can handle it on its own. Regedit is merely the GUI for accessing the registry, not the API. Though I haven't tested this.

Comment: @Amazed: I believe quite the opposite -- the shell doesn't handle any file type internally, it always launches `regedit "%1"` for a `.reg` file, as HKCR\.reg can also tell.